# Xcode Reverted to old version, how to restore?

Tags: ios, xcode, file, revert

After updating mavericks to the latest version, I restarted my macbook air, booted up xcode, and xcode prompted a message something like: "An outside editor changed text context, would you like to revert to old, or keep it?"

So without thinking I clicked revert to old, and now I have lost about 10 hours of code and can't find a solution to restore it.

Unfortunately I didn't store a snapshot recent enough, and I can't seem to find any other way through the forums and other search.

While I'm at it, does anyone know of a way so that it creates a snapshot automatically before exiting xcode?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: learn version control

Comment: How from "I clicked revert to old" you get "I have lost about 10 hours of code"? xCode won't open your project or what? Explain clearer, please.

Comment: My apologies for being unclear. When I opened xcode after rebooting, and then opened my project up, it prompted me with that message saying an external editor manipulated context of the files, and I clicked revert to old. So what happened, is that xcode thought something else manipulated the files, but really it was all the work I did in xcode before I did the OS upgrade. So all of that work, which was about 10 hours or so, was erased and reverted to what the files looked like previously. I have not closed xcode since, and it will not allow me to undo the mistake. I hope this is more clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description of the problem, nothing can be done unless you use version control or backup.

Using version control is a very good investment of your time, also making regular backups is a very good idea.

Comment: Ah, well I appreciate the feedback. At least I can take it as a lesson, and study up on version control. Thanks a ton!